# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase - Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read a value from a database but does not seem to be working. The purpose of the code is to take in a counter value from a user's UID in Firebase, that will change the source of an image. The counter is changed in another activity and works fine. I feel I am close but not sure what do do next. I have tried to print out the value but it does not print in the console.

Full disclaimer, I am new to android development and firebase so I apologise in advance if it is a simple mistake/correction.

Activity calling the database UPDATED:

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Menu";
    Button btn;
    public ImageView image;
    public static int counter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        // Add an image
        image = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.g1);
        //image.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("myImageResource",R.drawable.g1));
       
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("counter");

        
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                menuCounter uCount = dataSnapshot.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).getValue(menuCounter.class);
                System.out.println("Simon says" + uCount.counter);
                counter = uCount.counter;

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Counter is: " + counter);

        if (counter == 1) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.g2);
        }

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent WIP = new Intent(Menu.this, WIP.class);
                startActivity(WIP);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Getter class:

```
package com.alanlyne.tbm;

public class menuCounter {
    int counter;

    public menuCounter() {
    }

    public menuCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Activity changing the counter value:

```
public class WIP extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;

    DatabaseReference databaseName;

    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wip);

        databaseName = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("counter");

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Menu.counter = 1;
                Intent act2= new Intent(WIP.this,Menu.class);
//                act2.putExtra("myImageResource", R.drawable.g2);
                startActivity(act2);

                addCounter();

            }
        });
    }

    private void addCounter() {
        Menu.counter = 1;

        String id = databaseName.push().getKey();

        menuCounter counter = new menuCounter(Menu.counter);

        databaseName.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(counter);
        }
    }
```

Firebase image:

[image: The XMxqL line is that user's own UID that was generated when they signed up]

Comment: In your `menuCounter` class (consider renaming to `MenuCounter` to follow [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)), `int counter;` should declared as `public int counter;`. This is because each property is set directly (`uCount.counter = dataSnapshot.counter`) in `getValue(menuCounter.class)`, without using constructors or `getSomeVar()` and `setSomeVar()` functions. If this ends up solving the problem, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes, that works, but for some reason, the counter value is not updating or printing. I have updated the code above. It is updating inside the method but not outside it? I moved the if statement inside of it and it works but there is a small delay. Is this just it loading the info from firebase? Ideally, I would like the if statem,ent outside of the databse call